# How do I write browser specific javascript code?

Tags: javascript, browser

How do I write browser specific javascript code?
for example just to make the code work for firefox or ie using javascript.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for MSIE x.x;

if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //test for Firefox
```

[Read more in-depth here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml)

Note that it's usually better to detect features not browsers, as you shouldn't care what browser the end user is using as long as it supports your's features.